# Bad behavior of Promise.all in map of array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dictionary, promise

I am using Vue and i am trying to make some axios request in map over array but i get very bad result.

my function is :

```
  async getFavoriteRecipes(){
           try{
            let myRecipes=[]
            const response = await this.axios.get("https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/profiles/myprofile")
            let myFavoritedIds=response.data.favoriteRecipe;
            myRecipes= await Promise.all(myFavoritedIds.map(async (recipeInfo) =>{
                if(id.type==="spooncalur"){
                    const result = await this.axios.get("https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/recipes/"+recipeInfo.id)
                    myRecipes.push(result.data)
                    return myRecipes
                }
                else{
                    const result = (await this.axios.get("https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/recipes/userecipe/"+recipeInfo.id))
                    myRecipes.push(result.data)
                    return myRecipes
                }    
             }
            ))
            this.myFavoriteRecipe=myRecipes
           }
           catch(err)
           {
             if(err.response.status==='401'){
                 this.$root.store.username=undefined
                 this.$router.push('/login')
             }
              console.log(err.response)
           }
        }
```

i am expecting to get array of 6 json objects , but instead i get an array of 6 arrays and every array hold the same 6 json objects.
Someone can explain me why its happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, you want to have an array of the result's data of each request. So I would suggest instead of pushing the data to the `myRecipes` data to returning it. That would automatically "add" (or better replace) it in the list. The code would then look like this:

```js
async getFavoriteRecipes() {
    try {
        let myRecipes = []
        const response = await this.axios.get("https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/profiles/myprofile")
        let myFavoritedIds = response.data.favoriteRecipe;
        myRecipes = await Promise.all(myFavoritedIds.map(async (recipeInfo) => {
            if (id.type === "spooncalur") {
                const result = await this.axios.get("https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/recipes/" + recipeInfo.id)
                return result.data
            } else {
                const result = (await this.axios.get("https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/recipes/userecipe/" + recipeInfo.id))
                return result.data
            }
        }))
        this.myFavoriteRecipe = myRecipes
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.response.status === '401') {
            this.$root.store.username = undefined
            this.$router.push('/login')
        }
        console.log(err.response)
    }
}
```

If you don't understant the `map` function this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DC471a9qrU4 or https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

Ayk already explained the cause of the problem... but also code can be reduced to

```
const path = "https://david-matan-recipe-api-server.herokuapp.com/api/recipes/" + 
  id.type==="spooncalur" ? '' : 'userecipe/'
  
myRecipes = await Promise.all(myFavoritedIds.map(recipeInfo =>
  this.axios.get(path + recipeInfo.id)
))
```

No need to make `this.axios.get(path + recipeInfo.id)` async because Promise all get an array of promises as parameter, not result values